# Form I-130: Does a sponsor having a medical marijuana dispensary on their employment history risk rejection?

Tags: united-states, immigration

Simple question, will my sponsor having employment history with a medical marijuana dispensary cause her application to be rejected?

Follow-up: Will the sponsor be required to take a medical examination or just me?

Comment: Hello PlainText999!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our tour page, linked at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 2):

Only the beneficiary (you) needs to do the medical exam.

Regarding sponsorship - that is a very complicated question. I can't say whether the application would be rejected, but I can say that you will very likely be questioned regarding your connection to the business and whether you've done anything that could be considered trafficking under INA 212(a)(2)(C)

Comment: The more direct way of saying it is possibly yes as it is admitting to a violation of a federal criminal law, even though that law wasn't enforced and wasn't prosecuted.

Comment: more or less. As far as the applicant/beneficiary goes, he or she would need to admit to all elements of the crime in question in order for it to be legally sufficient to justify a denial (see Matter of K)